# Using numerous tables in a single page, is it a problem?

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

If i use multiple tables on a page say 15 tables in a single page then will it affect page performance?

Comment: Performance as compared to what?

Comment: Performance, I dont know much about using divs and css, feels a great sort of trouble in layout that's why using tables frequently. Will it effect any thing. Performance and any other factor u feel ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Any data on a page effects page-performance.** Nothing loads faster than something all the time.  The question, instead, should be "Am I using tables when I should be," or "Should I be handling this data differently?"

Imagine another question, "Can this platform support the weight of 15 things?" I think you would rightly ask me "That depends, how much do they weigh?"

#### Regarding Layouts

From your comment on the OP, it appears you're interested in this topic as it applies to layouts. In that case, yes. It does matter. Divs are the proper method of doing web-page layouts, and Tables are reserved for tabular data.

Comment: Isn't that like saying the only secure computer is one that isn't turned on? :)

Comment: Those aren't secure either :)

Comment: Ok, turned off, unplugged, with a dead battery. :-D

Comment: Is there a temp working near the machine who might confuse me for a manager if I called and told him to turn it on and run a few routine commands for me? :)

Comment: @Jonathan Sampson : I m developing a website that will be mostly related to database interaction for that i want my website to look gud too, moreover i alone is making this website and dont know much about websites, will it affect my page in loading

Comment: Shantanu, it *can*, but that doesn't necessarily mean it *will*. You'll need to tell us more about your data, how much information you're showing, how you're using tables vs. divs, etc.

Comment: @Jonathan Sampson I dont know how to explain you as this is my first website. I dont know how to use nesting of a div. I can position my outer div  but dont know how to position inner div wrt outer div. This is a big problem to me

Comment: Shantanu, I would suggest you look into something like the 960 Grid System. You can see a watch a video tutorial at http://net.tutsplus.com/videos/screencasts/a-detailed-look-at-the-960-css-framework/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this still applies but I remember IE used to not display a table until the whole table had loaded.

Answer (score 0):

It will be bigger in KB than to do it with ul or div tags ... but i dont think that you will notice the diference.